# Can anyone explain why my Apple storage is like this?

Tags: iphone, icloud

[image]
My iPhone storage bar has showed that my iCloud Drive exceeded my phone capacity which is extremely odd. Can anyone explain and have any clue to fix it? Moreover, my iPhone (12 mini) is constantly being warm, is it related to my storage?

I try to remove my the files from iCloud Drive but seems nothing happened, my iPhone still has the problem mentioned.

Comment: Does a restart of the phone change the values shown?

Comment: What do you see when you click on the iCloud drive size entry?

Comment: It’s the idea that you can store more data in iCloud than on your iPhone. It may also be shared with other devices, like 150’GB on your Mac.